# Use event handler to change button appearance

Tags: reactjs

I would like to build out my functional component BoldButton in which when the user clicks either the lowercase a or uppercase A, the text of the button is changed to **bold**. Below is my work in progress.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const BoldButon = () => {

    const [color, setColor] = useState("black")

    useEffect(() => {
        
    })


    const changeColor = () => {
        setColor("black")
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button  text={{style:color}} onClick={changeColor}>
                A   
            </button>
            <button text={{style:color}} onClick={changeColor}>
                a
            </button>
        </div>
    )
} 

export default BoldButon;
```

This was one problem I had when doing a mock technical interview so I would like to know how to solve it when using a functional component. **Not sure if I need to utilize useEffect in order to solve this.

Comment: `text={{style:color}}` - what is this supposed to do?

Comment: In this case I just wanted the text to be black, but looking at it now it might not be useful. I think I would need to use the ternary operator within the <button />.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there are a few problems with syntax to address:

1. text={{style:color}} not sure what this is supposed to do: text is not a standard or custom prop that you have set anywhere on the button component. Also, say you were to change the color of the button's text (which you could do with style={{color}} then you would be able to change it from let's say black to gray or black to yellow for different emphasis, but you seemed to say that you wanted different font-weight (bold vs not bold) is controlled by the CSS property font-weight (and that can be set in HTML or JSX through the style property that all elements can have.
2. if you have nothing in useEffect probably you can/should get rid of it. useEffect is useful for if the state of something changes and you need a side effect you can put it there (or it can be used as a strange componentDidMount which will only run after all parents have had their useEffect run.
3. For something like this it might be better to use a class and then you can set a number of style properties with a single string: like is-emphasized is a commonly used class that can change the font-weight to 600 and the color to black from a dark gray (if necessary).
4. You probably want individual states for each individual button (as you want each button to be bold if it was clicked: it seems based on your question).

```
    .is-emphasized {
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #000;
    }
```

But if not the simplest fastest way to approach this is:

```
    <button 
      style={{fontWeight: bold ? 'bold' : 'normal'}}
      onClick={changeWeight}
    >
     A   
    </button>
    <button
      style={{fontWeight: !bold ? 'bold' : 'normal'}}
      onClick={changeWeight}
    >
      a
    </button>
```

```js
function BoldButon() {

    const [capitalABold, setCapitalABold] = React.useState(false)
    const [aBold, setaBold] = React.useState(false);

    const changeColor = () => {
        setColor("black")
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button
              className={capitalABold ? 'is-emphasized' : ''}
              onClick={() => setCapitalABold(!capitalABold)}
            >
                A   
            </button>
            <button
              className={aBold ? 'is-emphasized' : ''}
              onClick={() => setaBold(!aBold)}
            >
                a
            </button>
        </div>
    )
} 

ReactDOM.render(<BoldButon/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
* {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.is-emphasized {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `useEffect` for this kind of functionality, you can utilize the `useState` hook to manage the variable that determines if the user has clicked on the button. Also, you can use the `useMemo` hook to keep the `style` object which returns either `bold` or `normal`. Please note that the `toggleBold` toggles the font weight so if a user is clicking multiple times it will switch between the `bold` and `normal`.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';

const BoldButon = () => {

    const [boldA, setBoldA] = useState(false)  
    const [boldB, setBoldB] = useState(false)

    const toggleBold = (buttonType) => () => {
        if(buttonType === 'firstButton') {
          setBoldA(prevState => !prevState)
        } else {
          setBoldB(prevState => !prevState)
        }
        
    }

    const buttonStyleA = useMemo(() => {
      return {fontWeight: boldA ? 'bold' : 'normal'}
    }, [boldA])

    const buttonStyleB = useMemo(() => {
      return {fontWeight: boldB ? 'bold' : 'normal'}
    }, [boldB])

    return (
        <div>
            <button style={buttonStyleA} onClick={toggleBold('firstButton')}>
                A   
            </button>
            <button style={buttonStyleB} onClick={toggleBold('secondButton')}>
                B
            </button>
        </div>
    )
} 

export default BoldButon;
```

Comment: Thank You for your response. So I am utilizing this at the moment but unfortunately when I click either button both turn out to be bold.

Comment: You didn't specify that only one should be bold once clicked. Let me fix that up.

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure about that either but since it said:

"lowercase a or uppercase A, the text of `the button` is changed to bold. B."

Seemed like maybe just the text of a single button needed to be bold. But yeah totally possible read of the question. Your answer is cool!

Comment: There might be some typos possibly, I didn't test this code, it was only written here on editor. But I hope you get the idea behind the logic and are able to fix any typos.